# C# How two properly wrap two objects

Tags: c#

I want to create an Action class that's a wrapper for an Input (defined in a DLL and cannot be edited) and a Wait object (defined by me).

I want to have a list of Actions and a method that takes Actions.

Would a wrapper class like this be the correct way to do it?

```
public class Action
{
    public Object action;
    public bool setAction(Object action)
    {
        if (action != typeof(Input) || action != typeof(Wait))
            this.action = action;
        else
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you just declare two parameters of their types?

Comment: Either create two versions of this method that differ by the type of an argument, or make a base class that the ```Input``` and the ```Wait``` will inherit from.

Comment: "action" delegate it what you are after i think, lookup c# func and Action

Comment: So maybe create ```public void myCustomMethod(Input input)``` and ```public void myCystomMethod(Wait wait)``` both calling the ```private void myCystomMethod(object object)``` that will handle the rest.

Comment: @mcjmnz This is to me the most reasonable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your `Action` wraps either an `Input` or `Wait` object. When you have a situation where you need to store a reference to an object that can be either one of a number of types, the best approach is typically to reduce those to a base common type or interface and use that instead.

So, identify what `Wait` and `Input` have in common, and put that in an interface. It's not really clear from your question what they're supposed to do here, so I'll just call it `IAction`.

```
public interface IAction
{
    void Act();
}
```

You can implement that interface directly on `Wait`, because it's your code. However, you don't control `Input`. Well, no worries, just create your own wrapper for it, and have the wrapper implement the interface:

```
public class InputWrapper : IAction
{
    private readonly Input _input;

    public InputWrapper(Input input)
    {
        _input = input;
    }

    public void Act() => _input.Whatever(); // delegate to input
}
```

And then you can play with those:

```
var actions = new IAction[] { wait, new InputWrapper(input) };
```

Notice how you can put a `Wait` directly because it implements the interface, but for `Input` you need to create a wrapper. This input to wrapper conversion is not done automatically (you could always overload a conversion operator for that, but it's not something I recommend).

Comment: With this solution, how would I create a list of Actions?
`Actions[] inputs = {new Input()}` returns `cannot convert Input to Actions`. In my code IStuff is equivalent to Actions. Casting the Input to InputWrapper doesn't work either.

Comment: I've edited the code, but basically you have to create the wrapper object first. I added a constructor to `InputWrapper` so you can create a wrapper from an input object.

Comment: awesome, thanks so much! It's working

Answer (score 0):

Presumably Input and Wait have a set of common properties and methods.
So just declare an interface or abstract class of what is in common and have each class inherit and implement it.
Then in your method declaration, use `public void myCustomMethod(IInterface obj)`

EDIT Nevermind, just re-read your question and saw that you don't have control over Input.

If you're really set on this, pass in as Object and use reflection - then, based on the reflected type, act accordingly.
I would, as others have said, just do multiple methods.

Comment: How will this work if user can't change the other dll?

Comment: Or just create a wrapper type, no need for reflection.

Comment: I read too fast, I just edited it. the answer :-)

Comment: If I wanted to have a list of Actions (type Wait or Input) would I have an interface too?